# Creating a jquery / php system to identify if a string contains the username of a user from another database

Tags: php, mysql, identity

I have an user section where users can upload a biography of themselfes. I want to integrate some code which will identify if the users biography contains an username of another random users. If the username is anywhere in the text, the username will be wrapped with a link to the users profile.

I've been thinking back and forrth to make a system which will do this, but i cant think of a way where i can go through the entire content of the users biography.

Anyone know how to set this up?

Comment: How do you want this to work? Like if someone uses an `@` symbol to tag a different user, like this `@username` OR should it work even if the biography has even the mention of the username?
If we have to go with the `@` option, it's fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it on displaying like that :

```
$text = "
Text who speak about Bob, Jessy and Kelian.
";

$usernames = array("Kelian", "Jessy");


// constructing links

$links = array_map(function ($username) {
    return "<a href=\"http://server/user/$username\">$username</a>";
}, $usernames);


// replacement

echo str_replace($usernames, $links, $text);
```

Comment: You're my man! This is exactly the simple solution i was looking for. Thumbs up!

Comment: Now that i'm just thinking, How will this work with a users database of 10000 names?

Comment: will it be to much of data in the array?

Comment: it would just take more time with more names. to save ressources you can cache the result instead of making this job on every page display

Comment: Okay, Thank you again